# Assigning global variable to a local variable

Tags: python, function, variables, global, local

When I assign a Global list to a local list and edit this local list both the list get edited. Is it because list in python are pointer, similar to array in C?

```
>>> source = [(0, 5), (1, 5), (2, 5), (3, 5), (4, 5)]
>>> def s():
...     source_queue = source
...     while len(source_queue)>0:
...             f(source_queue)
...
>>> def f(source_queue):
...     (x,y) = source_queue.pop(0)
...     print (x,y) in source
...     print source,source_queue
...
>>> s()
```

Output:

```
False
[(1, 5), (2, 5), (3, 5), (4, 5)] [(1, 5), (2, 5), (3, 5), (4, 5)]
False
[(2, 5), (3, 5), (4, 5)] [(2, 5), (3, 5), (4, 5)]
False
[(3, 5), (4, 5)] [(3, 5), (4, 5)]
False
[(4, 5)] [(4, 5)]
False
[] []
```

Comment: Do you have any question?

Comment: "similar to array in C?" - no. See http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.

Comment: they share the same reference, that's why.

Comment: Yes. How can I prevent the Global list by getting edited?

Comment: Damn! dupehammer is working at its full (and it's for the best!)

Comment: If you want to prevent the global list form being edited you can copy it : `new_list = old_list[:]`

Comment: Try `source_queue = list(source)`